# iPhone - how to change the build configuration to distribution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, configuration, ad-hoc-distribution

I have been following apple's instructions to get my app to iTunes.
I can not figure out how to open the Target info window so I can change the build to distribution.

I tried clicking on all the icons, left clicked.  Looked at all the menu items, tried the help, nothing is working.

Comment: Are you running Xcode 3 or 4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Follow these steps in Xcode 4

1.Click on the red area

[image]

2.Click here

[image]

3.And choose required configuration

[image]

---

If you don't have Distribution configuration then you can create it at project Info page here:

[image]

Comment: Ted,you can follow this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, IT WORCKED, but, when I clicked on the red part, it did not work, the drop down did not show the shemas, when I clicked on the project name to the left it worked.

Comment: BUT when I was trying to fix it, i brook it.  on the right hand side it no longer shows all my files, but is all grey saying "no filter restuls", any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XCode4 double click on project name as in the 2nd attached screen shot "Leaves".
Then the configuration window will open as in the 1st attached image and you can see in the 2nd image there is configuration,through which you can configure the setting.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was able to get there, but i saw a setting to add a configuration and the configuration that gets built by the command line, is that the same one that will get built by the sdk??????