# Function not defined in GDB IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gdb, cracking

I've developed a simple IOS application which Just validate pin/code value and print *"is validated"* if true, and *"is not validated"* if false .

what i did then i choosed *product->archive* the app and got it as "myapp.app" and upload it into my IOS phone, after that I used GDB trying to crack the application as (PoC), but when i try to put breakpoint as the following:

> *#(gdb) break -[viewController isValidCode]*
>
> *Function "-[viewController isValidCode]" not defined.*
>
> *Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])*

What is the reason behind this error ? Is there any preferences that we need to specify before using the app - during the archive step in XCode.

> *Reading symbols for shared libraries . done*
>
> *Reading symbols for shared libraries ........... done*
>
> *Reading symbols for shared libraries + done*
>
> *0x3b442eb4 in mach_msg_trap ()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you archive the product, it is built in the "Release" mode, where the debug symbols are stripped. `lldb` or `gdb` do not leverage the information in the `__OBJC` segment to try to get method names, they solely rely on the debug symbols.
What you would need to do is to break at a specific address, ie in gdb: `b *0x12345` where `0x12345` is the address of the implementation of `-[viewController isValidCode]`. 
To retrieve that address you can look at the assembly generated by xcode. Or more realistically, as you would do with an "unknown" binary; you could use tools such as `otool` or  the `class-dump` utility (look into the `-A`  and `-H` option)

Comment: Thanks, this is clear now, but if i do want to use the function name directly in the GDB what should the built mode be ? and where i can change that in the xcode ?

Comment: just figured out that i should use xcodebuild -configuration Debug in the command line :)

Comment: You can do that in the GUI too if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298916/where-is-set-the-active-build-configuration-in-xcode-4